# Is there a way to fit two distributions from exponential family and overcome discontinuity in parameters?

Tags: probability, distributions, fitting, mixture-distribution

I have data that follows LogNormal distribution in the body (high density region) of the distribution and it seems like it has an Exponential tail after a particular 'cut' point. Given that these two distributions are parametrised differently, I am curious if there is any way how the discontinuity in parameters can be overcome during the fitting process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer**

First, define $g$ and $h$ as the underlying log-normal and exponential distributions:

$$g(x|\mu,\sigma)=\frac{1}{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{\Big(-\frac{(\ln{(x)}-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\Big)}$$
$$h(x|\lambda)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$$

As whuber pointed out, the data could be modeled as a mixture of a right-truncated log-normal($\mu$,$\sigma$) distribution and a left-truncated exponential($\lambda$) distribution, where the truncation point, $\tau$, is the same for both distributions.

$$f_X(x|\mu,\sigma,\lambda,\tau,w) = \begin{cases} 
      w\frac{g_X(x)}{G_X(\tau)} & \text{for } x ≤ \tau  \\
      (1-w)\frac{h_X(x)}{1-H_X(\tau)}=(1-w)\lambda e^{-\lambda(x-\tau)} & \text{for } x > \tau
   \end{cases}$$

where $w\in[0,1]$ is the weight parameter. This distribution has 5 parameters and has a continuous CDF:

$$\lim_{x\to\tau^-}F_X(x)=\lim_{x\to\tau^+}F_X(x)=w$$

For continuity, we might say an attractive distribution would also have a continuous PDF at $\tau$:

$$w\frac{g_X(\tau)}{G_X(\tau)}=(1-w)\lambda e^{-\lambda(\tau-\tau)}$$

This constraint leaves four degrees of freedom for parameter values. Solve for $w$:

$$w\frac{g_X(\tau)}{G_X(\tau)}=\lambda(1-w)$$

$$w=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\frac{g_X(\tau)}{G_X(\tau)}}$$

For $x_1\in x|x_1>\tau$, the likelihood function is maximized at

$$\lambda=\frac{|x_1|}{\sum{(x_1-\tau)}}$$

I don't have closed-form solutions for the maximum likelihood values of $\mu$, $\sigma$, or $\tau$, so the final step would be to estimate them using numerical methods. In R:

```
library(ReIns) # for the rtlnorm function

rpieceMix <- function(n, mu, sigma, lambda, tau) {
  # generates random values from a piecewise truncated log-normal-exponential
  # distribution
  n0 <- rbinom(1, n, lambda/(dlnorm(tau, mu, sigma)/plnorm(tau, mu, sigma) + lambda))
  c(rtlnorm(n0, mu, sigma, tau), tau + rexp(n - n0, lambda))[sample(n)]
}

pieceMixMLE <- function(x) {
  # ML parameter estimation for a piecewise truncated log-normal-exponential
  # distribution
  n <- length(x)
  rngx <- range(x)
  
  fNLL <- function(params) {
    mu <- params[1]
    sigma <- exp(params[2])
    tau <- exp(params[3])
    if (tau > rngx[2]) return(-sum(dlnorm(x, mu, sigma, TRUE))) # w = 1
    if (tau < rngx[1]) return(n*(1 + log(mean(x)))) # w = 0
    a <- x <= tau
    x1 <- x[!a]
    lambda <- 1/mean(x1 - tau)
    w <- lambda/(dlnorm(tau, mu, sigma)/plnorm(tau, mu, sigma) + lambda)
    sum(a)*(plnorm(tau, mu, sigma, log.p = TRUE) - log(w)) - sum(dlnorm(x[a], mu, sigma, TRUE)) - length(x1)*(log(lambda) + log(1 - w) + lambda*tau) + lambda*sum(x1)
  }
  
  logx <- log(x)
  params <- optim(c(mean(logx), log(sd(logx)), log(as.numeric(quantile(x, 0.75)))), fNLL, method = "L-BFGS-B")$par
  sigma <- exp(params[2])
  tau <- exp(params[3])
  lambda <- 1/mean(x[x > tau] - tau)
  c(
    mu = params[1],
    sigma = sigma,
    lambda = lambda,
    tau = tau,
    w = lambda/(dlnorm(tau, params[1], sigma)/plnorm(tau, params[1], sigma) + lambda)
  )
}

set.seed(1799477253)
# generate 100K pseudo-random values
x <- rpieceMix(1e5, mu = 0, sigma = 1, lambda = 2, tau = 1.5)
# find the MLE
pieceMixMLE(x)
#>         mu      sigma     lambda        tau          w 
#> 0.01280112 1.00323380 2.00746298 1.50777035 0.84341726
```

The value of $w$ given the values of $\mu$, $\sigma$, $\lambda$, and $\tau$ used to generate `x`:

```
2/(dlnorm(1.5, 0, 1)/plnorm(1.5, 0, 1) + 2)
#> [1] 0.8429493
```

The estimates are similar to the values used to generate `x`.

---

**Original answer**

The question could describe a piecewise distribution with four parameters: the log-normal location and scale parameters ($\mu$ and $\sigma$) the rate parameter of the exponential distribution ($\lambda$) and the "cut" point ($\tau$).

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} 
  g_X(x)=\frac{1}{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{\Big(-\frac{(\ln{(x)}-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\Big)} & \text{for } x ≤ \tau  \\
  h_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x} & \text{for } x > \tau
   \end{cases}$$

For continuity, we might say an attractive distribution would have a continuous PDF. Since the same must be true of the CDF in order to have a valid distribution, there would be only two degrees of freedom when determining the parameters of the resulting distribution. For this reason, a better approach may be to find a distribution for your data that provides more flexibility (perhaps with more than two parameters).

But to estimate the parameters of this piecewise distribution, find the MLE while satisfying two equations:

$$g_X(\tau)=h_X(\tau)$$
$$G_X(\tau)=H_X(\tau)$$

The latter can be rearranged:

$$G_X(\tau)=1-e^{-\tau\lambda}$$
$$\lambda=-\frac{\ln{(G_X(\tau))}}{\tau}$$

Since $\tau$ is in the tail of the distribution, a good strategy would be to maximize a function that returns the likelihood given $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

To demonstrate, say the observed data are iid from our piecewise distribution with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$. In R:

```
mu <- 0
sigma <- 1

f <- function(tau, mu, sigma) {
  # 0 when the PDFs match at tau and the CDFs match at tau
  dlnorm(tau, mu, sigma) - dexp(tau, -log(plnorm(tau, mu, sigma, FALSE))/tau)
}

lambdaTau <- function(mu_sigma) {
  # given a vector containing mu and sigma, return a vector containing lambda
  # and tau that satisfy the PDF and CDF constraints
  mu <- mu_sigma[1]
  sigma <- mu_sigma[2]
  s0 <- sign(f(tau1 <- tau0 <- exp(mu + sigma^2/2), mu, sigma))
  while (s0 == sign(f(tau1 <- tau1*2^s0, mu, sigma))) {}
  tau <- uniroot(f, sort(c(tau0, tau1)), tol = 1e-8, mu = mu, sigma = sigma)$root
  c(-log(plnorm(tau, mu, sigma, FALSE))/tau, tau)
}

lambda_tau <- lambdaTau(c(mu, sigma))
(lambda <- lambda_tau[1])
#> [1] 0.7141922
(tau <- lambda_tau[2])
#> [1] 1.50579
```

Thus the distribution that satisfies the continuity constraints has a cut point $\approx1.5$, and the tail follows an exponential distribution with rate parameter $\approx0.714$.

Check the results graphically:

```
dpiece <- function(x, mu, sigma, lambda, tau, log = FALSE) {
  # PDF of the piecewise distribution
  a <- x > tau
  d <- numeric(length(x))
  d[a] <- dexp(x[a], lambda, log)
  d[!a] <- dlnorm(x[!a], mu, sigma, log)
  d
}

ppiece <- function(x, mu, sigma, lambda, tau) {
  # CDF of the piecewise distribution
  a <- x > tau
  d <- numeric(length(x))
  d[a] <- pexp(x[a], lambda)
  d[!a] <- plnorm(x[!a], mu, sigma)
  d
}

# check that the piecewise distribution meets the constraints
curve(dpiece(x, mu, sigma, lambda, tau), 0, 10, col = "red", ylab = "PDF")
curve(dlnorm(x, mu, sigma), 0, 10, col = "blue", add = TRUE)
legend("right", legend = c("piecewise", "log-normal"), lty = c(1, 1), col = c("red", "blue"))
curve(ppiece(x, mu, sigma, lambda, tau), 0, 10, col = "red", ylab = "CDF")
curve(plnorm(x, mu, sigma), 0, 10, col = "blue", add = TRUE)
legend("right", legend = c("piecewise", "log-normal"), lty = c(1, 1), col = c("red", "blue"))
```

The distributions are fairly similar, but the piecewise distribution has a shorter tail.

The following code demonstrates estimating the parameters. First generate some random values from the distribution described above:

```
rpiece <- function(n, mu, sigma, lambda, tau) {
  # generates random values from the piecewise distribution
  n0 <- rbinom(1, n, plnorm(tau, mu, sigma))
  r0 <- numeric(n0)
  nr <- n0
  while(nr) {
    r <- rlnorm(5, mu, sigma)
    r <- r[r < tau]
    if (length(r) >= nr) {
      r0[(n0 - nr + 1L):n0] <- r[1:nr]
      nr <- 0L
    } else {
      r0[n0 - nr + 1:length(r)] <- r
      nr <- nr - length(r)
    }
  }
  n1 <- n - n0
  r1 <- numeric(n1)
  nr <- n1
  while(nr) {
    r <- rexp(n, lambda)
    r <- r[r > tau]
    if (length(r) >= nr) {
      r1[(n1 - nr + 1L):n1] <- r[1:nr]
      nr <- 0L
    } else {
      r1[n1 - nr + 1:length(r)] <- r
      nr <- nr - length(r)
    }
  }
  c(r0, r1)[sample(n)]
}

set.seed(1019100615)
x <- rpiece(100, mu, sigma, lambda, tau)
```

Since the cut point is in the tail, use the use the MLE for a log-normal distribution on the entire dataset as the initial guess.

```
pieceMLE <- function(x) {
  # returns the MLE parameter estimates for the piecewise distribution from data "x"
  # c(mu, sigma, lambda, tau)
  logx <- log(x)
  fNLL <- function(mu_sigma) {
    lambda_tau <- lambdaTau(mu_sigma)
    -sum(dpiece(x, mu_sigma[1], mu_sigma[2], lambda_tau[1], lambda_tau[2], TRUE))
  }
  mu_sigma <- optim(c(mean(logx), sd(logx)), fNLL, method = "L-BFGS-B")$par
  c(mu_sigma, lambdaTau(mu_sigma))
}

pieceMLE(x)
#> [1] -0.09605132  0.94369706  0.80845984  1.57810878
```

These parameter values are close to the values of the distribution from which `x` were drawn, and they satisfy the continuity constraints.

Comment: The distribution described in the question has *four* parameters, not two, making it unclear what your notation means and what you are doing.  Why does it have four? Because it's a mixture of a Lognormal$(\mu,\sigma)$ distribution right-truncated at $\tau \gt 0$ and an exponential$(\kappa)$ distribution left-truncated at $\tau,$ *and the mixture weights can be adjusted to assure continuity of the PDF at $\tau.$*  The four parameters therefore can be taken to be $\mu,\sigma,\tau,\kappa$ and they all give distinct distributions with continuous PDFs.

Comment: Edited to try to clarify the notation. I hadn't considered a weight parameter. That would give the distribution more flexibility.

Comment: I see, thank you.  That strikes me as being too restricted to be of much use in this application, but the approach you take ought to work when extended to accommodate all four parameters.  Although the estimate of the threshold $\tau$ is likely to be (highly) uncertain, many other properties of the distribution ought to be well estimated, assuming the tail really is exponential.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. One thing that I was not able to follow was why would these distribution have two degrees of freedom?

Comment: I was considering the mixture as well, however I am not sure if these would not affect the tail considering that Lognormal is defined from 0 to inf.

Comment: @whuber. I like the idea of a mixture instead of a piecewise since it leaves 4 degrees of freedom (I think). It'll be more work to code up, but I'll give it a try when I get a chance of someone doesn't get to it first.